# Выравнивание текста в GridLayout в коде

Tags: android

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь создать таблицу произвольной длины. Таблица создается, но не получается выровнять текст по середине ячейки

Разметка

```
  <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </GridLayout>
```

код

```
GridLayout table =(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);   
GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
param.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;    
for(int i=0;i<40;i++){
    text=new TextView(this);
    text.setLayoutParams(param);
    table.addView(text);
    text.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    text.setText(new Integer(i).toString()+" ");
}
```

Если пытаюсь применить text.setLayoutParams(param); то текст уезжает непонятно куда. А без него выравнивание по правому краю.

Comment: В чем смысл, задавать разметку с определенными параметрами, а потом в коде опять их задавать? Если вам нужно чтобы в `GridLayout` `view` элементы позицинионировались по центру задайте `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: Вставляю android:gravity="center" в опции GridLayout -изменений нет. выравнивание так же по правому краю

Comment: `text.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);` удалите эту строку. Ну или вам уже дали нужный ответ ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете неверную константу для установки `gravity`: `View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER`(4). Вам нужна `Gravity.CENTER`(17). Измените на:

```
text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

В этом случае сам `TextView` будет на всю ширину родителя, а текст в нём центрирован.

Второй вариант, как советовали в комментарии, поставить гравити у родителя и сделать ширину `TextView` `wrapContent` и не трогать его гравити:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
</GridLayout>
```

И в коде:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
param.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;    
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
    text = new TextView(this);
    text.setLayoutParams(param);
    table.addView(text);
    text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

В этом случае сам `TextView` будет шириной с контент с текстом выровненным по левому краю, но располагаться по центру родители.